# What was the first publication documenting AT&T syntax assembly language?

Tags: history, assembly, unix, x86

What was the first publication to document what is (now) known as AT&T syntax assembly language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [sampablokuper](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/11467/sampablokuper) (OP) has noted, the UNIX Programmer's Manual cites PAL-11R as the source of the syntax, with only minor changes. So I've found a published book from [May 1971, the PAL-11R Assembler Programmer's Manual](https://ia600602.us.archive.org/9/items/bitsavers_decpdp11do11RAssemblerProgrammersManualMay71_2572677/DEC-11-ASDB-D_PAL-11R_Assembler_Programmers_Manual_May71.pdf) that describes the syntax. Given that the syntax was probably around in 1969, this is still almost definitely not the earliest.

---

The earliest I can find with a casual web search is [the UNIX Programmers Manual of November 1971](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/bellLabs/unix/UNIX_ProgrammersManual_Nov71.pdf) ([better version](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/man71.pdf)). If you scroll to page 195 (page 5), you'll see this:

> ```
> 173700: mov      $177472,r0                   12700;177472
>         mov      $3,—(r0)                     12740;3
>         mov      $140000,—(r0)                12740;140000
>         mov      $54000,—(r0)                 12740;54000
>         mov      $—2000,—(r0)                 12740;176000
>         mov      $5,—(r0)                     12740;5
>         tstb     (r0)                         105710
>         bge      .—2                          2376
>         jmp      *$5400Q                      137;54000
>
> 173740: mov      $177350,r0                   12700;177350
>         clr      —(r0)                        5040
>         mov      r0,—(r0)                     10040
>         mov      $3,—(r0)                     12740;3
>         tstb     (r0)                         105710
>         bge      .—2                          2376
>         tst      *$177350                     5737;177350
>         bne      .                            1377
>         movb     $5,(r0)                      112710;5
>         tstb     (r0)                         105710
>         bge      .—2                          2376
>         clr      pc                           5007
> ```

That, if I'm not mistaken, is AT&T syntax!

---

The earliest paper on UNIX, according to [this source](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html), is [this paper](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/readings/ritchie78unix.pdf). This document is from July 1974, so it's no good as a first, and does not include any AT&T syntax anyway. It does, however, state that the first version of UNIX was made circa. 1969–1970. This isn't necessarily a limit on the earliest that the syntax could've been described in a publication, since it might predate UNIX; I don't know.

Comment: Thanks! I had not previously seen `mov` used by itself in AT&T assembly code (always `movb`, `movl`, etc.), but that does not mean `mov` was (is?) not valid AT&T syntax. (I am new to the syntax.) I will upvote this and provisionally mark it as correct. If any other answers come along, with earlier examples, I will move the "correct" mark accordingly.

Comment: @sampablokuper Thanks. I see that no on-boarding is necessary, then! :-) This is the first I've heard of AT&T syntax (actually, that's a lie, but I've never really looked at it before) so I can't answer you that, unfortunately.

Comment: On page 21 of the first PDF in your answer, the man page for `as` states, "`as` is based on the DEC-provided assembler **PAL-11R**, although it was coded locally. Therefore, only the differences will be recorded [in this man page]." The differences seem fairly minor. So, it seems that what we now call "AT&T syntax" is largely due to DEC rather than AT&T. Interesting.

Comment: Isn't it, as already mentioned, just a normal syntax for PDP-11? Isn't "at&t syntax" is the way to express i386 (and amd64) assembly with the source to the left and destination to the right? This convention is routinely used in PDP-11 assembly, VAX assembly and m68k assembly, but not in i386 one.

Comment: @lvd AT&T and Intel are the names for the two surviving Assembly syntaxes.

Comment: DEC used ```#foo``` for an immediate operand in -11 assemblers; the Unix guys apparently preferred ```$foo```, which to my eyes lacks any mnemonic significance.  Similarly ```@``` became ```*```.  Does anyone know the rationale or is this just personal taste?

Comment: @another-dave [Ask a new question](/questions/ask) and more people will see this to be able to answer it.

Comment: @another-dave: # and @ were apparently hard to type (Unix Assembler Reference Manual §8.1 - Dennis M. Ritchie, referenced in my answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193827/questions-about-att-x86-syntax-design), fuz says _"As the UNIX tty driver used @ and # as control characters, $ was substituted for # and * for @._ at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244028/what-was-the-original-reason-for-the-design-of-att-assembly-syntax

Comment: @ninjalj - Aha! of course! I'd forgotten those characters had special meaning in Unix.

Comment: @ninjalj If another-dave isn't going to post a question, you could write a question/self-answer pair and cash in on those juicy reputation points.

Comment: I considered it answered so didn't see any need to post a question.  Clearly I'm not entirely familiar with the local culture.  I'm happy for ninjalj to claim credit.

Comment: @another-dave The site's around, not for the people who _ask_ to get answers to their questions, but for _future_ readers to get answers to their questions. Often questions that won't benefit future readers are closed before people put effort into answering them, because they're really specific (though I don't think we've ever had one of those).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Note that Plan 9 syntax too survived through the Go project.